# REST API call is not working through SQL Server Job (2016)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Following is my code, which works good, if i execute the code manually through the SSMS. However, when tried to execute through the SQL Server job, it fails. I'm using SQL Server 2016.

I tried using the execute as user syntax for the underlying stored procedures

```
    Exec @hr=sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0', @Object OUT;
    IF @hr <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @Object

    Exec @hr=sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'get', @url, 'false'
    IF @hr <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @Object

    EXEC @hr=sp_OAMethod @Object, 'SetRequestHeader', NULL, 'X-API-TOKEN', 'SOME TOKEN' 
    IF @hr <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @Object

    EXEC @hr=sp_OAMethod @Object, 'SetRequestHeader', NULL, 'Content-type', 'application/json' 
    IF @hr <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @Object

    Exec @hr=sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send'
    IF @hr <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @Object

    Exec @hr=sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText', @json OUT
```

Comment: Please do include the errors logs as well.

Comment: *Don't* use the `sp_OAMethod` methods. They *aren't* "the way to call REST APIs* by any stretch. They are legacy methods that call a 19 year old library that *can't* handle modern REST APIs. They even require weakening security which should make it quite clear they *shouldn't* be used

Comment: If you want to call a REST API from a job, write a simple Powershell script and call it. All this code is more or less the same as a single [Invoke-RestMethod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-6) call.

Comment: Thank you Lamu and Panagiotis for your help.  I was able to resolve the issue by calling the stored procedure using the SSIS package.  There seems to be privilege issue with the "SQL Server Agent" account, and the SSIS proxy has all the privileges to invoke the REST API methods.

Comment: @Panagiotis, Thank you for the details on alternative method to call the REST API, i will certainly try the new methods henceforth for calling the REST API